# Can I create a Warlock that can Sneak Attack with Eldritch Blast?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, warlock, sneak-attack

Starting a DnD 4e game where I'm making a Halfling Warlock.

I've given him a background where he used to be part of a Thieves' Guild and I thought I could perhaps flavour him as an ex-assassin. I've pored over the books I have available to me but I can't find anything like a Feat that could potentially let me sneak attack with my Eldritch Blast, which is classified as a "basic ranged attack" — but no affiliated weapon skill (where Sneak Attack requires Dagger, Light Blade, or Sling).

Is there any way to make this work, or something like it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you are getting Sneak Attack from the Sneak of Shadows multiclass feat.

As you say SA requires you to use a light blade, a hand crossbow, a shortbow, or a sling. What it does not require is the attack to be a weapon attack, so as long as you are using one of those as an implement you can apply your SA damage. The easiest way to do this would be to take Arcane Implement Proficiency and choose light blades or if you worship Sehanine you can take Moonbow Dedicate to gain shortbows as implements.

Another option to get a similar ability would be to take the Shadow Initiate multiclass feat which allows you to use the Assassin's Shroud power twice an encounter.

Comment: I've opted for the multi-class feat you've provided - I've only got PHBs 1 and 2, so I didn't know about the assassin feats that were in PHB3. It trains me in Stealth, and can stack with my Warlock's Curse - it's pretty cool :D

Answer (score -2):

If you can get your hands on a pact blade, might be able to make it work.

PS, take a look at the Hexblade Gloom pact from Heroes of Shadow.